# Django Open ID - Assign permissions to users who have never logged in by email

Tags: django, openid, django-authentication, django-openid-auth, django-authopenid

I'm using django-auth with the django-auth-openid extension to use OpenID (specifically, Google) to log users into my site. I have a user base of about 90 who will be using the site. All of them have Google accounts, and will be using them to access the site. Since the user base is set (there is no registration allowed, only admins can add users), I already have an exhaustive list of all of my users, including their email addresses and other information. How can I allow these users to login with their Gmail addresses without making them register first? Essentially, I'd like to make django-auth-openid match OpenID Gmail addresses to rows in the existing django-auth Users table. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth) library (which has Django support built in). The documentation for use with Django isn't great, but between the docs and the provided example it was relatively easy to integrate it with my existing django-auth setup. After that, I just deleted the 'create_user' pipeline from the SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE tuple in my settings, and, that way, only users with existing OpenID connections were allowed in (no new registrations occurred from OpenID logins). This meant, though, that I had to create those connections (between OpenID identifiers and Users) manually, but that was pretty easy to do just using the Django Python shell.